# How to remove the extra space before header and after footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to remove the extra space above header and after footer of my blog. How to remove it?
I am using WordPress and Genesis News Pro Theme on my blog.

You can take a look at the blog - https://web.archive.org/web/20160306192700/http://recruitmentapplicationforms.in/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `margin:60px auto` in class `.site-container`

```
.site-container {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
margin: 0px auto;  /* change 60px to 0px */
max-width: 1140px;
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for the homepage, but rest of the pages are having the same extra spaces .. how to remove this extra space completely from the entire blog?

Comment: That should work for all pages if you have added/overridden the main style.css  Do let me know if any issue. Also delete cache and refresh the page.

Comment: cache cleared and yeah I am using some genesis plugins to modify some of the theme's functionality but don't know whether this is happening because of those plugins.

Comment: I checked all your pages and issue has been resolved. I can't see the top and bottom space now. All good on my computer. Do let me know if any issue. I am sure its related to cache or something.

Comment: You are right and the issue has been resolved. thanks for the help and time.

Answer (score 0):

You have applied `margin: 60px auto;` to your `.site-container` class. Just change it to `margin: 0px auto;`

Currently, the site has 60px margin at top and bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of margin style you are using in "site-container" class.

If you do not want margin at the top and bottom then you specify explicit margins for left and right i.e.

margin-left and margin-right instead of using just margin:60px auto;